# Java SpringBoot Always Returning 404 Status

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am completely new to SpringBoot and i have following along with a Course on YT.

**Request:**

[image]

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.sbt.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  @GetMapping
  public String hello() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

In the course he is able to get a response of "Hello World" but i keep getting

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Nov 25 16:24:31 CST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

I've added the `@RestController` annotation like other similar questions with answers to recommend, but i keep getting the error.

I also restarted the server and retried and keeping getting the error.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sbt</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What request did you send?

Comment: added the request above. `localhost 8080`

Answer (score 2):

Please share your pom.xml and application.properties too. because this codes look correctly. Perhaps there can be problem in those files.

Comment: added the pom file.

Comment: So before spring boot 3 version that case works by default. in Spring boot version 3.0.0 you need to add following small updates:
Option 1:
just replace from GetMapping to GetMapping("/")
Option 2:
Add @RequestMapping("/") above to class after @RestController
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. I guess you have to map it.

```
 @GetMapping("/")
  public String hello() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, add ComponentScan in SpringBootApplication resolved 404 error:

```
@ComponentScan(value = {"work.example.controller"})
```